# Top position of SVG elements related to document

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I am trying to get the correct top position of a SVG element related to the webpage.

If I try to align the top of the element with the top of the page, setting it to 0, the element gets almost completely hidden behind the top margin of the page.

In one example, the element has 45px of height, but to align its top with the top of the page I have to set it to be 36px. Another element has 22px of height, and to align it to the top, I have to set it to be at 18px.

Specifically in my case, when the page loads I get the top and left position of the element related to the page (`offset().top/left` in jquery) and put another element over it. As this new element is dragged and dropped by the user, I update the position of the SVG element to the new position of the new element. The problem is that the new position os the SVG element is never precisely the same as the other element, and the difference gets bigger as the SVG element is bigger.

Is it possible to get the exact position of these elements to make sure my elements will be properly aligned?

[image: When I set the top to 0, the element disappers, but if I set top to 0 + height - (an arbitrary difference related to its height), it works]

Comment: Is it possible that you could post something legible?

Comment: maybe the first paragraph was difficult to understand. but try skipping it and you will understand

Comment: maybe you could post actual code instead of images whose resolution is too small to be worth a damn

Comment: what kind if code do you need? css? there is no css being applied to the svg elements

Answer (score 0):

The `y` position in a `<text>` element refers to the baseline.  If your text is at `y=0` as in your image, then the baseline of the text is at the very top of the SVG and most of the text will be off the top of the SVG and thus not visible.